# What should be DynamoDB key schema for time sliding window data get scenario?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

What I never understood about DynamoDB is how to design a table to effectively get all data with one particular field lying in some range. For example, time range - we would like to get data created from timestamp1 up to timestamp2. According to keys design, we can use only sort key for such a purpose. However, it automatically means that the primary key should be the same for all data. But according to documentation, it is an anti-pattern of DynamoDB usage. How to deal with the situation? Could be creating evenly distributed primary key and then a secondary key which primary part is the same for all items but sort part is different for all of them be a better solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Global Secondary Index` which in essence is

> A global secondary index contains a selection of attributes from the base table, but they are organized by a primary key that is different from that of the table.

So you can query on other attributes that are unique.

I.e. as it might not be clear what I meant, is that you can choose something else as primary key that is possible to be unique and use a repetetive ID as GSI on which you are going to base your query.

**NOTE**: One of the widest applications of NoSQL DBs is to store timeseries, which you cannot expect to have a unique identifier as PK, unless you specify the timestamp.

Comment: Ok, if I have a primary key like { partition: unique_id, sort: - } and a secondary key like { partition: const, sort: timestamp } - does it have an advantage over just having { partition: const, sort: timestamp } primary key (in case I never get items by id) ?

Comment: It will allow versatiltiy in different type of queries, in case you need information for different purposes. Here's a good example https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GSI.html . As performance advantage, there won't be any.